# Imageresizing limt to subfolder (umbraco media folder)

Tags: umbraco, imageresizer

How can i configure imageresizing.net to only be active in the /media folder of an umbraco installation?

In the IIS the media folder is a virtual folder, and I would prefer it stayed that way and not being turned into an application

Answer (score 0):

You can move the cache around by setting the directory in the config files - see http://imageprocessor.org/imageprocessor-web/#cacheconfig

One problem we found is that the cache directory has to be under the web site hierarchy, if you want to move it out then you'll need to make it a hard symbolic link.

Comment: How will configuring the cache location help me prevent scaling of images outside of the media folder?

Comment: Think I misread your question - I read it as you want to move the location of the media folder - I gather this isn't what you want to do

Comment: True, thats not what i want to do :-)